# How to identify the differences between a branch and the master to the point where the merge was made?

Tags: git

I have a branch, x, and would like to recover all the files that have been modified in this branch, so I researched, `git diff branch...master`, should solve the problem, but I have doubts if this command will return the differences from the commit that the branch was created up to the commit limit of the merge, or if it will make up the last version of the master, I would like to know only the files that were modified from the creation of the branch, until the last commit before the merge.

I need modified files in commits marked in red (added and modified files):

[image: modified files in commits marked in red]

Answer (score 2):

Because of a handy property of git history given the following graph:

[image]

Given no conflicts

- `diff(a, i) == diff(e, j)`
- `diff(a, e) == diff(i, j)`

You can compare the merge commit with its parent and get the same information, and it will include any changes made to resolve conflicts on the merge.

```
git diff M M^1
```

Assuming you merged the branch into master (not the other way around followed by a fast forward in which case it would be M^2).

[image: History]

Comment: Switching the order of the parameters to `git diff M^1 M` would show the diff from the branch, while your command shows the opposite (added lines are shown as removed and the other way around). If only the file names are required, add the parameter `--name-only`, which will print a list of file names.

Answer (score 1):

Simply resetting your `master` branch to the state before merge would be an easier solution. Just find the commit id of the master branch before the merge.

```
git checkout master
git log # or gitk
# identify the commit id before the merge
git reset --hard <pre_merge_commit_id>
```

You might consider testing the commands on an temp branch forked out of `master` first to avoid any "mishappenings".

Comment: seems like a good idea, thanks for now, I'll test, if it's okay I'll mark the answer

Comment: This will also remove the commits made after the merge (the top two in the graph from the question). You should also be aware that this will rewrite the history. If you have already made the merge available to anyone (e.g. by pushing it somewhere), someone else might still have the version with the commits to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

[`git merge-base master branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) gives you the common ancestor for the merge. Not the point where the branch was created (git doesn't keep that info) but usually it's a good approximation.

Then do `git diff` from the branching commit to the tip of the branch:

```
git diff $(git merge-base master branch)..branch
```